# Is there any plugin available in cordova to upload file with any extension

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am working on cordova hybrid mobile application and needs to upload files from user phone to server i am done with server side code but in cordova end i can't able to select file other than image.

I have used below code to choose file but it never open folders other than folder which contain images

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(documentURI){
                //Success

            },function(message) {
                //Error
            },{
                destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                mediaType       : navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
            }
        );
```

Please help me with any solution or plugin which allow to select any type of file from mobile phone.

Comment: Which plugin you have used and what type of file you want to upload ? please specify.

Answer (score -1):

for select file you can try this plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mfilechooser  or https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser

and for transfer file use this https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: What to do with Facebook Connect plugin with file transfers ??

Comment: I know that file transfer is used to upload and download file through cordova application, But problem here is fullpath and .toURL() method of these plugins sometimes in some specific devices not give files extension and provide us a temp path at server without extension so in these case we can't able to generate file. Do you ever use it ?